# Howto compute the factorial of x

Tags: c, operators, factorial

how to get the value of an integer `x`, indicated by `x!`, it is the product of the numbers 1 to x.

Example: `5! 1x2x3x4x5 = 120.`

```
int a , b = 1, c = 1, d = 1; 
printf("geheel getal x = ");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("%d! = ", a);
for(b = 1; b <= a; b++)
{
     printf("%d x ", c);
     c++;
     d = d*a;
}
printf(" = %d", d);
```

Comment: By the looks of it, the variable c is redundant.

Comment: @Alexander: Someone probably told him to write it in c++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how to get the som of an integer x, indicated by x!, is the product of the numbers 1 to x.

Did you mean `factorial` of x ?

Change `d = d*a;` to `d = d*b` inside the loop

Comment: And you can printf() and multiply to the same variable also! They are quite flexible and will not perish from shared usage.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do:

```
for(b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
  d *= b;
}
// d now has a!
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the optimal implementation in size and speed:

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    static const int f[13] = { 1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, /* ... */ };
    if ((unsigned)x < (sizeof f/sizeof f[0])) return f[x];
    else return INT_MAX+1; /* or your favorite undefined behavior */
}
```

Hint: `x!` (`x` factorial) does not fit in an int except for very very small values of `x`.

Comment: Excellent answer! I'm glad someone pointed out that critical overflow issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
d = d * b;
```

instead of

```
d = d * a
```

and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a lot of redundant code there, that might be why you did not spot the error yourself.

To calculate the factorial, you only need the accumulator (`d` in the above code) and the input (`a`). Why?

Answer (score 0):

My code is not good as other but it works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned int fattoriale (int n){
    if (n == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return n * fattoriale(n-1);
    }
}

int main() {
    int tmp, num;
    cin >> num;

    tmp = fattoriale(num);

    cout << "Stampo il fattoriale del numero inserito: " << tmp << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    int f;
    if (x == 0)
    {
        f = 1;
    }
    else if (x > 0)
    {
     f = x*factorial(x-1);
    }
    return f;
}

int main()
{
   int n = 0;
   cout << factorial(n);

   return 0;
}
```